# Wget a page on imgur

Tags: wget

I am trying to save a page and its images from imgur.com.

All I get is the pages, no images.

Take this URL for example:

[http://imgur.com/gallery/l5NXz](https://imgur.com/gallery/l5NXz)

I have tried this:

```
wget -p -k  http://imgur.com/gallery/l5NXz
```

No image is saved.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those imgur pages span hosts. The images themselves are not on `imgur.com` so 
you will need to include the `-H` option and possible others. If you use the preference of the author of `wget`'s `man` page:

```
 wget -E -H -k -K -p  http://imgur.com/gallery/l5NXz
```

you can do

```
 firefox imgur.com/gallery/l5NXz.html
```

and get the images from the local download.

Answer (score 4):

The following shell code uses `lynx -dump -listonly` to fetch the list of images to download, extracts the URLs with `awk` and then fetches the images with `xargs wget`.

```sh
mkdir pics
cd pics
lynx -dump -listonly  'http://imgur.com/gallery/l5NXz' | 
    awk '/\.jpg$/ {print $2}' | xargs wget
```

Adjust the regexp in the `awk` statement if you need to download `.gif`, `.png`, etc as well as `.jpg`.

Comment: IIRC, some older versions of `wget` can't handle multiple URLs on the command line.  In that case, use `xargs -n 1 wget`.